# How can we get the url of an image in a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, webkit

I just want to extract the url of an image that I touched from a UIWebView. How can we do that ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you'd have to use JavaScript to do this... or at least, that's one way of doing it. You can have a JavaScript function (say, `URLofImageClicked`) that returns the URL of the clicked image. In Objective-C, you would make a call to that function using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`. I would guess you would make that JavaScript call when `UIWebView` detects a click.

Hope this helps!